# Is it possible to fetch needed data in one query?

Tags: mysql

I have a database containing tickets. Each ticket has a unique number but this number is not unique in the table. So for example ticket #1000 can be multiple times in the table with different other columns (Which I have removed here for the example).

```
create table countries
(
   isoalpha varchar(2),
   pole varchar(50)
);

insert into countries values ('DE', 'EMEA'),('FR', 'EMEA'),('IT', 'EMEA'),('US','USCAN'),('CA', 'USCAN');

create table tickets 
(
  id int primary key auto_increment,
  number int,
  isoalpha varchar(2),
  created datetime 
);

insert into tickets (number, isoalpha, created) values
(1000, 'DE', '2021-01-01 00:00:00'),
(1001, 'US', '2021-01-01 00:00:00'),
(1002, 'FR', '2021-01-01 00:00:00'),
(1003, 'CA', '2021-01-01 00:00:00'),
(1000, 'DE', '2021-01-01 00:00:00'),
(1000, 'DE', '2021-01-01 00:00:00'),
(1004, 'DE', '2021-01-02 00:00:00'),
(1001, 'US', '2021-01-01 00:00:00'),
(1002, 'FR', '2021-01-01 00:00:00'),
(1005, 'IT', '2021-01-02 00:00:00'),
(1006, 'US', '2021-01-02 00:00:00'),
(1007, 'DE', '2021-01-02 00:00:00');
```

Here is an example:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3f4ba4/6

What I need as output is the number of new created tickets for each day, devided into tickets from USCAN and rest of world.

So for this Example the out coming data should be

```
Date | USCAN | Other
'2021-01-01' | 2 | 2
'2021-01-02' | 1 | 3
```

At the moment I use this two queries to fetch all new tickets and then add the number of rows with same date in my application code:

```
SELECT MIN(ti.created) AS date
        FROM tickets ti
        LEFT JOIN countries ct ON (ct.isoalpha = ti.isoalpha)
        WHERE ct.pole = 'USCAN'
        GROUP BY ti.number
        ORDER BY date

SELECT MIN(ti.created) AS date
        FROM tickets ti
        LEFT JOIN countries ct ON (ct.isoalpha = ti.isoalpha)
        WHERE ct.pole <> 'USCAN'
        GROUP BY ti.number
        ORDER BY date
```

but that doesn't look like a very clean method. So how can I improved the query to get the needed data with less overhead?

Ii is recommended that is works with mySQL 5.7

Comment: Please add the expected output based on your sample data above.  Explanations would also help.

Comment: There is already the expected output in the text

Comment: I don't know how to describe it in more details. At the end its pretty easy. I need the number of new created tickets for each day. So if there were 5 new tickets created on the 2021-01-01 for USCAN and 3 new tickets for other poles I need the output of the date 2021-01-01 and the number of tickets for USCAN = 5 and Other = 3. The problem is, that each ticket number can be multiple times in the table that's my problem. Otherwise the query would be easy

Comment: What is the meaning of "new" in the context of number of new tickets created per day?

Answer (score 2):

You may logically combine the queries using conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT
    MIN(CASE WHEN ct.pole = 'USCAN'  THEN ti.created END) AS date_uscan,
    MIN(CASE WHEN ct.pole <> 'USCAN' THEN ti.created END) AS date_other
FROM tickets ti
LEFT JOIN countries ct ON ct.isoalpha = ti.isoalpha
GROUP BY ti.number
ORDER BY date;
```

Comment: This is helpful to reduce it to one query but I doesn't count the tickets by itself. So it is an improvement but not the optimal solution I guess

Comment: What is the logic for counting tickets themselves?

Comment: Number of tickets created on a date without duplicate ticket numbers.

Comment: I'm confused.  Do you want to aggregate by ticket or by date?

Answer (score 1):

You can create unique entries for each date/country then use that value to count USCAN and non-USCAN

```
SELECT created,
   SUM(1) as total,
   SUM(CASE WHEN pole = 'USCAN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as uscan,
   SUM(CASE WHEN pole != 'USCAN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as nonuscan
FROM (
    SELECT created, t.isoalpha, MIN(pole) AS pole
      FROM tickets t JOIN countries c ON t.isoalpha = c.isoalpha
    GROUP BY created,isoalpha
    ) AS uniqueTickets
GROUP BY created
```

Results:

```
created             total   uscan   nonuscan
2021-01-01T00:00:00Z    4       2       2
2021-01-02T00:00:00Z    3       1       2
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3f4ba4/45/0

Comment: Tim was right about the ELSE 0 though - otherwise there's a risk on NULL in the count column.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the answer of SQL Hacks I found the right solution

```
SELECT created,
   SUM(1) as total,
   SUM(CASE WHEN pole = 'USCAN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as uscan,
   SUM(CASE WHEN pole != 'USCAN' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as nonuscan
FROM (
    SELECT created, t.isoalpha, MIN(pole) AS pole
      FROM tickets t JOIN countries c ON t.isoalpha = c.isoalpha
    GROUP BY t.number
    ) AS uniqueTickets
GROUP BY SUBSTR(created, 1 10)
```